# Port MySQL script to MS SQL -> simultaneous data asignement and retrieval

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, migration

I have been trying to make this work for hours but I can't really find a way to do it. I have a MySQL script that I need to migrate to MS SQL 2014, however, I can't seem to make it work. As far as I have understood, the big issue is that MySQL allows this kind of instructions:

```
SELECT @row_number = @row_number + 1, hora_int FROM table1;
```

where you assign a value at the same time you retrieve data, but MS SQL does not.

I have a relatively big script which has that issue:

> ```
> SELECT GLOBAL.year, GLOBAL.month, '1111111' as metric_id, GLOBAL.margin as metric_value FROM (SELECT A.year,
>          A.month,
>          CASE
>            WHEN A.month = 1 THEN (@csum_fdo := A.imp)
>            ELSE (@csum_fdo := @csum_fdo + A.imp) END as margin
>   FROM (SELECT Act.year, Act.month, Act.imp - Pas.imp as imp
>         FROM (SELECT year(tie.date) as year, month(tie.date) as month, sum(importe) as imp
>               FROM accounting con,
>                    dim_time tie,
>                    dim_account cta
>               WHERE con.account_date = tie.date
>                 AND con.account = cta.nivel_10
>                 AND cta.level_id = '2'
>                 AND con.subtype_id <> 'O'
>               GROUP BY year(tie.date),
>                        month(tie.date)) Act,
>              (SELECT year(tie.date) as year, month(tie.date) as month, sum(importe) * -1 as imp
>               FROM accounting con,
>                    dim_time tie,
>                    dim_account cta
>               WHERE con.account_date = tie.date
>                 AND con.account = cta.nivel_10
>                 AND cta.level_id = '3'
>                 AND con.subtype_id <> 'O'
>               GROUP BY year(tie.date),
>                        month(tie.date)) Pas
>         WHERE Act.year = Pas.year
>           AND Act.month = Pas.month) A,
>        (SELECT @csum_fdo := 0) E) GLOBAL
> ```

Can anybody point me in the direction of what I have to do to recreate the code in MS SQL? Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My big problem lied in this line:

```
CASE
           WHEN A.month = 1 THEN (@csum_fdo := A.imp)
           ELSE (@csum_fdo := @csum_fdo + A.imp) END as margin
```

but as Gordon Linoff pointed me. this problem could be solved with window functions, the right translation od that function is:

```
SUM(A.imp) OVER(PARTITION BY A.Year ORDER BY A.month) as margin
```

it ended up being easier than I thought
Thanks a lot and I hope it can help others as well

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server and (MyQL 8+), you use window functions.  The equivalent of:

```
SELECT @row_number = @row_number + 1, hora_int
FROM table1
ORDER BY col;
```

is:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col), hora_int
FROM table1;
```

If you provide sample data and desired results, it is much easier to figure out what functions you really need.

Comment: I could not post data because it was confidential, but your answer pointed me in the right direction, I have posted an answer with the solution, thanks a lot